# How to receive json POST request using web2py

Tags: python, json, post, web2py, webrequest

I'm very new to `web2py` and I'm trying to use it for testing remote server's application (I send a http POST request using `python requests` with file to process and expect to get counter POST request with report in `json` and display it in shell or save to file). I found following code for similar issue for XML data

```
# Controller code:
def index(): 
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/xml'
    xml = request.body.read()  # retrieve the raw POST data
    if len(xml) == 0:
        xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><root>no post data</root>'
    return response.render(dict(xml=XML(xml)))

# View code:
{{=xml}}
```

but I can't make proper changes that will allow to use it for my purpose.
So the question is: how to simply receive `json` data via POST request and save it directly on my computer or to display it somehow using `web2py`? No buttons, upload fields, data bases needed.. only to get data from incoming request

Answer (score 0):

In your client:

```
import requests
:
your_url='http://domain.com/app/controllerfile/j'
r=requests.post(your_url, json=jsonData)
```

In a web2py controller file 'controllerfile':

```
import json
def j():
    with open("json.txt","a") as f:
        json.dump(request.vars,f)
return
```